# Running exec on wget commands in a file from bash script ignores wget options

Tags: bash, exec, wget

If I run this shell script, I get exec causing wget to act goofy.

```
echo "wget http://www.google.com/ -O -  >> output.html" > /tmp/mytext
while read line
do
exec $line
done < /tmp/mytext
```

It acts like wget is operating on three different urls

```
wget http://www.google.com/ -O -  
wget >> 
wget output.html
```

The first command spits the output to STDOUT and the next two wget commands fail as they are nonsense.

**How do I get exec to work properly?**

I'm using exec instead of simply calling bash on the file because if I use exec on a large list of wget calls I get more than one wget process spawned. Simply calling bash on a file with a large list of urls is slow as it waits for one wget operation to complete before moving onto the next one.

Versions:
GNU Wget 1.15 built on linux-gnu.
GNU bash, version 4.3.0(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using exec instead of simply calling bash on the file because if I
>   use exec on a large list of wget calls I get more than one wget
>   process spawned.

No.   When `exec` is called, it does not spawn a new process.  It *replaces* the existing process.  See `man bash` for details.

> Simply calling bash on a file with a large list of urls is slow as it
>   waits for one wget operation to complete before moving onto the next
>   one.

True.  Fortunately, there is a solution.  To run a lot of processes in parallel, run them in the background.  For example, to run many `wget` processes in parallel, use:

```
while read url
do
    wget "$url" -O -  >> output.html &
done <list_of_urls
```

The ampersand at the end of the line causes that that command to run in the background in parallel with everything else.  The above code will start new `wget` processes as fast as it can.  Those processes will continue until they complete.

You can experiment with this idea very simply at the command prompt.  Run

```
sleep 10s
```

and your command prompt will disappear for 10 seconds.  However, run:

```
sleep 10s &
```

and your command prompt will return immediately while `sleep` runs in the background.

`man bash` explains:

> ```
>    If a command is terminated by the  control  operator  &,
>    the  shell  executes  the command in the background in a
>    subshell.  The shell does not wait for  the  command  to
>    finish,  and the return status is 0.
> ```

Comment: I feel awful silly. I have no idea why I was looking for a more extravagant solution than just backgrounding the wget op. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use

```
exec $(cat /tmp/mytext)
```

Comment: I just tested that and it behaves the same way where wget acts as if there are three inputs.